# My android app is incompatible with my device

Tags: android, compatibility

I developed an android app and I published it on Google Play.
For some reason, In the app-page on the store this following message is display: "This app is incompatible with your device.״
anybody know why? and what I need to to for delete this message?
My app **should** work for any cell phone that has internet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.eilamshapira.routeburntracker">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xxxhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="MAINACTIVITY"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

        <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ReferralPage"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="OPENMILFORD"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <service
        android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
</application>
```

from my build.grade file:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.eilamshapira.routeburntracker"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The reason will most likely be the Minimum API level you specified in your build.gradle file. Make sure that you target an API level that is lower or equals your device's android version. Also, even if you have for example android 7.0 and then you specify API level 24 as your minimum API, then keep in mind that devices with a lower android version (API level) will be incompatible as well.

You can find a list of API levels and Android versions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: I am adding now the build.grade file. I have SDK level 24 on my phone, and the app apt to level 15...

Answer (score 0):

You should also add all numerical `screenDensity` values. See here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html